# datetime get the hour in 2 digit format

Tags: python, date, datetime

When I get the hour of a time, it prints it in the 24 hour clock like this;

```
time1 = datetime.datetime.strptime("08/Jan/2012:08:00:00", "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S")
print 'hour is ', time1.hour

> time is  8
```

I'm trying to get it to show 08, instead of 8. For hours that are double digits its fine, but as soon as it gets to a single digit I'm trying to get that 0 in front of it.

I could potentially do 'time1.time' and then convert to string and then split it, and then convert the hour back into a datetime object, but this is pretty long winded and was wondering if there's a simpler solution?

Answer (score 12):

Just dump it back to string using [`.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.strptime("08/Jan/2012:08:00:00", "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S")
>>> dt.hour
8
>>> dt.strftime("%H")
'08'
```

Comment: Thank you @alecxe for saving me so much agony! Worked really well.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have leading zero for `int`:

```
>>> type(time1.hour)
<class 'int'>
```

That's why you have no choice but convert `time1.hour` to `str` first and then manipulate the format.

You can go with @alecxe solution (which seems elegant and right) or simply use something like that:

```
>>> "{0:0>2}".format(time1.hour)
```

Comment: Why use `>`? If you use `{0:02d}` instead, then the `=` format is implied and  you get sign handling for free. See the [format spec](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec).